# how to use ECDSA key to generate ECPrivateKey in kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

**i have key String like below**

```
val keyBase64Str = "BAqKWv7ac4kVFXSKcbCSJNQcZEWhoDMBVx+H1sUXZBh9gQcdiHlNJprY51aPf5yXRlwY0smXYNs7oYIBBqBoPUWkJZEO05O+Jb463/d1x7qHT1T3V7XL2nN3XHkq06jvuw=="

val keyArray = keyBase64Str.base64DecodetoByteArray()
//keyArray size is 97 byte,65byte publickey + 32byte privatekey
if(keyArray.size >= 97){
    keyPairArray.copyInto(publicKeyArray, startIndex = 0, endIndex = 65)
    keyPairArray.copyInto(privateKeyArray, startIndex = 65)
}
```

**i want to do signature, so need generate ECPrivateKey**

**//generate code like below but will exception**

```
val ecParameterSpec: ECParameterSpec = ECNamedCurveTable.getParameterSpec("secp256r1")
val privateKeySpec:ECPrivateKeySpec = ECPrivateKeySpec(BigInteger(privateKeyArray), ecParameterSpec)
var privateKey:PrivateKey? = null
try {
    val keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC")
    privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(privateKeySpec)
} catch (e:Exception){
    Log.e("test",e.toString())
    //exception is below
    //java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: Must use ECPrivateKeySpec or PKCS8EncodedKeySpec; was org.bouncycastle.jce.spec.ECPrivateKeySpec
}
```

//error log

> 2024-01-23 18:20:01.136 16430-16430 System.err
> com.dlink.mydlinkunified             W
> java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: Must use ECPrivateKeySpec
> or PKCS8EncodedKeySpec; was org.bouncycastle.jce.spec.ECPrivateKeySpec
> 2024-01-23 18:20:01.154 16430-16430 System.err
> com.dlink.mydlinkunified             W    at
> com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLECKeyFactory.engineGeneratePrivate(OpenSSLECKeyFactory.java:74)
> 2024-01-23 18:20:01.155 16430-16430 System.err
> com.dlink.mydlinkunified             W    at
> java.security.KeyFactory.generatePrivate(KeyFactory.java:399)
> 2024-01-23 18:20:01.156 16430-16430 System.err
> com.dlink.mydlinkunified             W    at
> com.google.chip.chiptool.DeviceControllerInitData.getPrivateKeyFromRaw(DeviceControllerInitData.kt:120)
> 2024-01-23 18:20:01.157 16430-16430 System.err
> com.dlink.mydlinkunified             W    at
> com.google.chip.chiptool.DeviceControllerInitData.init(DeviceControllerInitData.kt:87)
> 2024-01-23 18:20:01.158 16430-16430 System.err
> com.dlink.mydlinkunified             W    at
> com.dlink.unify.ui.main.wifi.wizard.matter.page.MatterStartPage.initView(MatterStartPage.kt:42)
> 2024-01-23 18:20:01.159 16430-16430 System.err
> com.dlink.mydlinkunified             W    at
> com.dlink.unify.ui.base.BaseFragment.onViewCreated(BaseFragment.kt:131)
> 2024-01-23 18:20:01.160 16430-16430 System.err
> com.dlink.mydlinkunified             W    at
> androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:2974)
> 2024-01-23 18:20:01.162 16430-16430 System.err
> com.dlink.mydlinkunified             W    at
> androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:543)
> 2024-01-23 18:20:01.163 16430-16430 System.err
> com.dlink.mydlinkunified             W    at
> androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
> 2024-01-23 18:20:01.164 16430-16430 System.err
> com.dlink.mydlinkunified             W    at
> androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2177)
> 2024-01-23 18:20:01.165 16430-16430 System.err
> com.dlink.mydlinkunified             W    at
> androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2088)
> 2024-01-23 18:20:01.166 16430-16430 System.err
> com.dlink.mydlinkunified             W    at
> androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1990)
> 2024-01-23 18:20:01.167 16430-16430 System.err
> com.dlink.mydlinkunified             W    at
> androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run(FragmentManager.java:524)
> 2024-01-23 18:20:01.168 16430-16430 System.err
> com.dlink.mydlinkunified             W    at
> android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) 2024-01-23
> 18:20:01.169 16430-16430 System.err
> com.dlink.mydlinkunified             W    at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 2024-01-23
> 18:20:01.170 16430-16430 System.err
> com.dlink.mydlinkunified             W    at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 2024-01-23 18:20:01.171
> 16430-16430 System.err              com.dlink.mydlinkunified
> W     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7397)
> 2024-01-23 18:20:01.171 16430-16430 System.err
> com.dlink.mydlinkunified             W    at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 2024-01-23 18:20:01.173
> 16430-16430 System.err              com.dlink.mydlinkunified
> W     at
> com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
> 2024-01-23 18:20:01.174 16430-16430 System.err
> com.dlink.mydlinkunified             W    at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:952)

any body share a sample? thx~~

Comment: what exception are you getting? Please paste the exception with the stacktrace

Comment: exception is java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: Must use ECPrivateKeySpec or PKCS8EncodedKeySpec; was org.bouncycastle.jce.spec.ECPrivateKeySpec

Comment: please paste whole stacktrace to the question body

Comment: i have upload error log thx